# where to get signature, password, username for live production paypal express checkout

Tags: paypal

ok, I have sandbox working perfectly with the sandbox username, password, signature.

Now, I login to paypal and look around for this signature and I can't find it anywhere.  Where do I get the signature for live production paypal.

Also, do I use the username/password of my account?  (I would rather not)....is there anything where I can set the username and password to use so anyone with access to production can't just login to paypal as me.  I use express checkout and I think I am the business paypal right now.

and I can't seem to find the "todo list" section this post refers to

https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/EC_setup_signature

I also tried this but there is no Api Access in the left column
http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?99345-Where-is-API-Signature-Code

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API signature is under the user profile under selling tools > api access.

If you have it working already you should see that at no time do you need the account name and password for the paypal account.

Comment: I don't need the username, password.  Darn, the example had this in it so I thought I had to have it.....  paypalSdk.put("acct1.UserName", username);
  paypalSdk.put("acct1.Password", password);
  paypalSdk.put("acct1.Signature", signature);

Comment: and I see that it gives you a new username, password now that I requested the api stuff.....sweet.